Submitting flink job in remoteEnvironment
I have a jobmanager, taskmanger running in docker.And in separate java program/Micro service1, i created a flink job jar with all the dependencies and conf.yaml. From another MicroService2, i need to submit the jar to jobmanager and started it. I used something similar to following
 StreamExecutionEnvironment
        .createRemoteEnvironment("172.18.0.5", 6123, getConfigurationFromFlinkYaml(),"target/biggis-tiledb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
        .fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        .filter(x -> x > 3)
        .print();


From MicroService2 logs i can see that, i am getting below error message.
"Error while waiting for job to be initialized".
From jobmanager logs i am getting below error
2024-12-11 18:52:59,588 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: XXXXX(1/1) (c006a1cb920305bac5f4954aead84abd_cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0_2069) switched from DEPLOYING to FAILED on 172.19.0.9:42467-7a262c @ taskmanager.YYYY (dataPort=46503).
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:87) ~[flink-dist-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig.toConfiguration(ExecutionConfig.java:1209) ~[flink-dist-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:627) ~[flink-dist-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562) ~[flink-dist-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_392]

FLink version used is 1.18.1. When i printed "environment.getConfiguration()", it is having all the configurations properly. But from jobmanager logs i see that some configurations are not properly loaded why?. What am i missing?
